# ArrayList insertion and retrieval order

Tags: java, collections

Suppose I insert 5 strings in an `ArrayList`. Will the order of insertion and retrieval from the `ArrayList` be the same?

Comment: It is one thing to try it out once. It is another to be sure that it is going to be the same every time.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Yes, ArrayList is an ordered collection and it maintains the insertion order.

Check the code below and run it:

```
public class ListExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        myList.add("one");
        myList.add("two");
        myList.add("three");
        myList.add("four");
        myList.add("five");
    
        System.out.println("Inserted in 'order': ");
        printList(myList);
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Inserted out of 'order': ");

        // Clear the list
        myList.clear();
    
        myList.add("four");
        myList.add("five");
        myList.add("one");
        myList.add("two");
        myList.add("three");
    
        printList(myList);
    }

    private static void printList(List<String> myList) {
        for (String string : myList) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
Inserted in 'order': 
one
two
three
four
five


Inserted out of 'order': 
four
five
one
two
three
```

For detailed information, please refer to documentation: [`List (Java Platform SE7)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: +1 for including a link to the Java doc that clearly explains that the ordering.

Comment: Sample output would be useful

Comment: Excellent example. +1 for this.

Comment: An example is not a proof, but the link is

Answer (score 143):

**Yes**. ArrayList is a **sequential list**. So, insertion and retrieval order is the same.

If you add elements **during retrieval**, the order will not remain the same.

Comment: If the OP "inserts" at the end, also called adding.

Comment: the second statement means if during the time of retrieval by one thread another thread intervenes to add a new element . then the order doesn't remain same

Answer (score 38):

If you always add to the end, then each element will be added to the end and stay that way until you change it.

If you always insert at the start, then each element will appear in the reverse order you added them.

If you insert them in the middle, the order will be something else.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it will always be the same. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

> Appends the specified element to the end of this list. Parameters: e
>   element to be appended to this list Returns: true (as specified by
>   Collection.add(java.lang.Object))

ArrayList `add()` implementation

```
public boolean More ...add(E e) {
    ensureCapacity(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes it remains the same.
but why not easily test it? Make an ArrayList, fill it and then retrieve the elements!

Comment: That's no proof though.

Comment: Same order is just one of possible result of test. If implementation is blackbox, same order might be specific case. Example is sorted list. If you add elements to sorted list in proper order you can get them in sorted order (which is just a particular case), but if you add them in random order you get them ordered. Testing ArrayList without checking implementation will just state "most probably order is the same".